# Remove (decompose) <a> element from BeautifulSoup select result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've got a HTML on which I work with BeautifulSoup:

```
<h1>
    <img src="CHN.jpg" alt="image">
        Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor
    <a class="button" href="/en/top300">
        See more information
    </a>                    
</h1>
```

With a simple select and get_text

```
soup.select('h1:nth-child(1)')[0].get_text().strip()
```

I'm getting (\n = newlines)

```
Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor \n\n\n See more information
```

But I would like to get rid of the "See more information" which is in `<a>` tags. 
I've tried to use `decompose()`, but it doesn't work on a select result. How can I bring decompose() to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some options for you.

**Option 1:**

One way around that is split at '\n', don't include any white space, then you'll have a list of each text element. Then in this case, you only want the first item.

```
import bs4

html = '''<h1>
    <img src="CHN.jpg" alt="image">
        Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor
    <a class="button" href="/en/top300">
        See more information
    </a>                    
</h1>'''


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

text = [ item.strip() for item in soup.text.split('\n') if item.strip() != ''][0]

print (text)
```

**Output:**

```
print (text)
Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor
```

**Option 2:**

Find that `<a>` tag, and get the previous sibling:

```
html = '''<h1>
    <img src="CHN.jpg" alt="image">
        Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor
    <a class="button" href="/en/top300">
        See more information
    </a>                    
</h1>'''


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

text = soup.find('a').previousSibling.strip()
print (text)
```

**Output:**

```
print (text)
Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor
```

**Option 3:**

This is probably the way I would go about it.
Find the `<img>` tag, and get the next sibling:

```
html = '''<h1>
    <img src="CHN.jpg" alt="image">
        Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor
    <a class="button" href="/en/top300">
        See more information
    </a>                    
</h1>'''


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

text = soup.find('img').nextSibling.strip()
print (text)
```

**Output:**

```
print (text)
Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer has already covered all the necessary tricks to fetch the required text. However, If you still want to use `.decompose()` or `.extract()` then the following should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlelem= """
<h1>
    <img src="CHN.jpg" alt="image">
        Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor
    <a class="button" href="/en/top300">
        See more information
    </a>                    
</h1>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlelem, 'lxml')
[elem.extract() for elem in soup.select("a.button")]
item = soup.select_one("h1").get_text(strip=True)
print(item)
```

Output:

```
Zhuzhou Wide-Ocean Motor
```